# Share ssh-agent socket or any other named pipe between windows 10 and cygwin

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cygwin, pipe, socat

Cygwin [emulates sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086038/what-mechanism-is-used-by-msys-cygwin-to-emulate-unix-domain-sockets) by opening port and adding the port number and a "login" secret to a file instead of using windows named pipes.

Further there seems to be no access to Windows named pipes from cygwin.

How can I then access a named pipe (e.g. //./pipe/openssh-ssh-agent) from cygwin and vice versa (e.g. with socat)?

Comment: I'm looking for exact same thing! I'm the maintainer of https://github.com/evsar3/sshfs-win-manager and I'm trying to implement the use of the Windwos 10's OpenSSH key agent in my program. However, SSHFS-Win uses a cygwin environment and I can't access the named pipe from there.
Please, let me know if you can make this work!

Comment: @evsar3: if you just want to use the win 10 openssh key agent in cygwin as you describe, my own preliminary answer below should actually. However, I guess you do not want to bundle both socat and plink with your GUI.

Comment: Exactly, I wouldn't like to bundle any other piece of software, but I'm guessing that this is not possible. Anyways, if you discover how to make it, I would be very appreciated if you can tell me. Congratulations, great research so far!

Answer (score 1):

After reading this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10976357/148337) and looking at https://github.com/jstarks/npiperelay/ I at least managed to get one direction done using socat and putty's plink (I somehow had a bit of trouble with npiperelay):

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/openssh-ssh-agent,umask=066,fork EXEC:"PLINK.EXE -serial //./pipe/openssh-ssh-agent",pipes
```

I actually build an [agent-bridge](https://gist.github.com/riedel/2002835932b073cea836fb171aa27a51) that works nicely to let keepassxc manage my ssh-keys on cygwin.

The other way around seems to be a bit more tricky without writing a dedicated program but possible, as its done by the [keepass plugin](https://github.com/dlech/SshAgentLib/blob/master/SshAgentLib/CygwinSocket.cs) . Please add to this answer or add more straight forward ways without running tons of processes or writing custom code.

Comment: Here is gist to emulate ssh-agent: https://gist.github.com/riedel/808529121892efdba444ac82df4c5f15